# net core 2.0 nested async Task Await methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, task

I'm a doing a `Net core 2.0 Application`.

I am testing `nested async Task Await` methods. I understand the meaning of Async method, but in nested methods, I reach a point when it turns difficult to understand.

I did this simple example where I reach an undesirable result.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Testexample();
}

public static  void Testexample()
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-------Main thread starting-------");
        Task task = GetStrLengthAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Main thread contiune ..");
        Console.WriteLine("-------Main thread end-------");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string a = ex.Message + ((ex.InnerException != null) ? ex.InnerException.ToString() : "");
    }
}        


static async Task GetStrLengthAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("GetStrLengthAsync starting ");
    string str = await GetString2();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("VALUE JJJ" + i);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(str);
    Console.WriteLine("GetStrLengthAsync end");
}


static Task<string> GetString2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("GetString starting");
    return Task<string>.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("VALUE I" + i);
        }
        return "GetString value";
    });
}
```

In this Example...

`Main` calls `Testexample` method

`Testexample` calls `GetStrLengthAsync(),` where it calls `GetString2()`
and after that run a For int.. sequence...

The problem I found is that after returns `GetString2()` call, it exit  `GetStrLengthAsync()` method and it does not run `For int.. sequence...`

Why?

How can I execute another sentence after

```
string str = await GetString2();
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't awaiting your async task your doing nothing with it

```
Task task = GetStrLengthAsync();
```

this just creates a task you need to await that task which means you need to call it from another async function.   But your calling this from a synchronous function, so you aren't leverage async at all you're just creating more problems

If you are attempting to call an async function from a sync function you need to call

```
GetStrLengthAsync().Result
```

but this may cause dead lock because your do not configure await.  This [blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) by Stephen Cleary may help you understand async better